# Which Stack community will answer my website cPanel link problem

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I had created an ecommerce website named "www.bookslab.in". I want to block my cpanel link for users who are accessing my website. Link is www.bookslab.in/cpanel. If any I.T. specialist user go to my www.bookslab.in/cpanel link then he should go on my homepage link.

Comment: If anything don't ask on Server Fault, given [this warning](http://serverfault.com/tags/cpanel/info). Oh, and it looks like you asked this same question on [magento](http://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/141023/revisions) but I advise to not abuse the question bump feature like you did there

Comment: Not I.T. specialists but the users who can go to my cpanel link.

Comment: So where should i ask this question. I had asked on Magento Stack but i did not get any answer there

Comment: Um, [you asked on Magento and got answers](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/141023)...

Comment: Yeah i got answers but that answers are to block the admin panel link of magento. If i ask for the cpnal link the users are telling me to go on the cpanel forum website

Comment: I see two answers that tell you how to block cPanel. If they don't solve your problem then you should edit your question to explain why... editing your question to add and remove the same sentence ~40 times isn't the way to go about it (and I'm surprised the post hasn't been locked because of it).

Comment: I had apologize for that edits to @Marius. There are 2 answers there but regarding cpanels they say to redirect to cpanel forums if i do so then on  that forums i did not got my answer

Comment: [Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels?](//meta.serverfault.com/q/8094)

Comment: @Salman one of the answers quotes a suggestion from cpanel forums but the other suggests a htaccess 301 redirect, why doesn't that work?

Comment: Yeah i had also checked that solution but  that also does not worked & i had also put the comment for the failure of answer

Comment: saying it doesn't work doesn't help anyone much; why doesn't it work? Your question explicitly asked for a htaccess redirect, which is what that answer gave you...

Comment: Yeah correct i had done the changed as instructed in my .htaccess file but that code does not working that is why i want the right stack forum to answer my question

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this question:

> I had created an ecommerce website named http://example.com. I want to block my cpanel link for users who are accessing my website. Link is example.com/cpanel. If any I.T. specialist user go to my http://example.com/cpanel link then he should go on my homepage link.<sup>1</sup>

should be asked anywhere.

The question in this form simply lacks the details, attempts, research results and expected outcome. At best it is unclear.

Before anything else you should make clear *how* you expect the blocking to take place. Can you only use cPanel it self? Do you have other means, like Apache or nginx. And do you still expect to be able to access /cPanel? If so, how are legit attempts allowed access to that resource?

Your question is not ready to be asked which was explained in the comments on your magento question and the lack of an answer that suits you is another indication of that.

When you worked out those details a [search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=cpanel%20-site:stackoverflow.com%20block%20access) can limit the possible sites your question might be on-topic. User [David Postill](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292650/which-stack-community-will-answer-my-website-cpanel-link-problem#comment950817_292650) provided a useful link to [Where can I ask questions about web hosting control panels?](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8094/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-web-hosting-control-panels)

I do know one thing for sure. Questions about [cPanel](https://serverfault.com/tags/cpanel/info) are off-topic (or at least strongly discouraged) on Server Fault. That is the only recommendation I can give you so far.

---

1. I would be very careful with linking to your site too much. It might be considered spam. The question at hand doesn't need your website name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So should i change now the old question in the same way you had suggested me now

Comment: I don't know. If adding those details you have obviously researched within 5 minutes makes the question still fit for magento, sure.

Comment: Okzz i try  & get back to you

Comment: I didn't just turn into your personal coach to get your question fixed, right?

Comment: Yeap correct no problem

Comment: You shouldn't make any modifications to your existing question, because, it's not on topic on any Stackexange Website, additionally, you have in the past abused the edit system

Comment: So what to do now & i dont know why i got -7 vote down for this question